# Organization with administrative network can't reach our website

Tags: firewall, nat, wordpress

Not sure if I've worded this correctly, so help me if I didn't.

I'm a web developer hosting a Wordpress website for a client (I'm not really a Wordpress expert, just trying to maintain the site while building a new one). The site is hosted on Cloudways, the DNS is managed through telenet.be (a Belgian internet company).

The site works fine, except for one organization that works with its own administrative NAT network. For some reason, they are not able to reach the site from that network.

I have checked for security plugins in the Wordpress site, blocked IPs and ports at Cloudways (hosting) and telenet (dns) level, but everything seems fine, there's also no sign of the client's IP in any access logs. When trying another site that's hosted on the same Cloudways server with the same IP however, it works fine.

I'm obviously missing something here, if someone can help me find a solution (or a way to find the actual problem) that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the site's domain that of the company (or a subdomain of it)? If so, it's probably them having a separate internal DNS system. Do a `dig example.com` from inside their network.

Comment: no, the site's domain is not that of the company trying to reach it.

Comment: What **does** happen when they try? DNS error? Server error? Blocked page message?

Answer (score 0):

My bet is, the problem is on their end.
Have one of their networking guys talk to you.

Are they using a proxy? 
Are they able to resolve your IP?
Can they ping it from the perimeter?
...
Good luck!